# How do I remove the default 'my cms' text from my drupal 7 webpage with the bartik theme?

Tags: 7

I have recently created a webpage with drupal 7 and currently have the bartik theme applied. However, I have encountered what I assume is a trivial issue but have been unable to fix it. The site has the default text **'my cms'** appearing in the banner across the top of all pages and I have been unable to remove it. I assume it is the site's slogan, but I have not been able to locate where that is set in either the the admin of the site or the files of the site.

[Here](http://gamedevgrotto.com/) is the site to show what I am talking about.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That *My CMS* text is the *Site name* setting value. You can change it from the setting page on /admin/config/system/site-information.